# Invocation of C++ code from python and python code from C++

Tags: python, python-embedding

Is it possible to invoke a C++ code from python and after that invoke another python code from that C++ code?

I have a C++ .so/.dll library which have to be called from a python wrapper code. C++ logic is doing some stuff and calculations and after that, it have to call to another python code. That python code will also do some calculations and return reaults to the C++ code. C++ will continue its logic and return the results to the python wrapper code.

Is there any pragmatic way to implement that? Without going to new threads or processes?

There is an option to use python Embedded. But I did not find any documentation or examples on how to implement python --> C++ --> python invocations in the same process.

Comment: Since you mention C++, I'd say have a look at Boost.Python or pybind11. Of course, you can do it just with the low level Python API, but that's a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by using [Cython](https://cython.org/). It supports interfacing with both C and C++ code from Python.

I think you will find this particular [section](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html) of the docs useful.